# How to filter subscribed data Angular-Meteor way

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

Let say we need to show filtered tasks on view, first step we got all the list of tasks buy publishing/subscribing:

Publish:

```
Meteor.publish("tasks", function(options){
    return Tasks.find(options);
});
```

Subscribe:

```
var allTasks = $meteor.collection(Tasks).subscribe('tasks', {});
```

And now, let say I need to see in $scope only tasks that have 'active' variable set to true.

Something like this:

```
$scope.active_tasks = getFilteredTasks(allTasks, {active: true})
```

How do I replace the getFilteredTasks(allTasks, {active: true}) to get tasks that have only active==true variable?

I know that we can set 'options' when subscribing to tasks like:

```
{active: true}
```

But it isn't helps to resolve the issue. The goal is to subscribe only once and later use filters to show only part of tasks.

I still not finished the [Angular-Meteor tutorial](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial), so it may be explained later, if you can please point me on right tutorial it will greatly speed-up my learning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

OK. It looks like the solution is on Angular side.
So in controller we get all the tasks:

```
$scope.active_tasks = $meteor.collection(Tasks);
```

And on view side we filter them:

```
<input ng-model="freeText">
<tr ng-repeat="task in active_tasks | filter:freeText ">
    <td>{{ task }}</td>
</tr>
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

@pumych solution is a valid one. 
You could also use

```
$scope.$meteorSubscribe ('tasks'); 
$scope.activeTasks = $meteor.collection (function (){ 
// active tasks will only be the filtered result
return Tasks.find (active: true) ; 
});
```

Read about data flows in Angular Meteor here https://medium.com/@tally_b/coll-pub-sub-with-angular-meteor-cb13fe48f5701. Check out the example and github code for more details.